# Replace old value with new value excluding the children

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex, wordpress

The initial text of A, B, C, D, and the number need to be removed in the frontend because I require it in the backend.

The HTML structure of table row is like this:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key, field) in nbd_fields" ng-show="field.enable &amp;&amp; field.published" class="ng-scope">
  <td class="ng-binding">A,B,C,D: 1 - Auswahl Wunschkarte : <b class="ng-binding">Wähle eine Option</b>
  </td>
  <td ng-bind-html="field.price | to_trusted" class="ng-binding"></td>
</tr>
```

Before Input:

[image: Before input]

Current Output:

[image: Current output]

If you notice that the selected option is also not visible. Is it because of the $(window).load() ?

Required Output:

[image: Required output]

Code that I am using:

```
jQuery(".ng-scope td.ng-binding:first-child").text(function(i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,""); 
 });
});
```

How can I make it so that it does not affect the `<b>` tag inside?

I used the above code for the steps heading with a different selector on the same page* and it worked because it did not have any children to alter.

I had to wrap it around `$(window).load()` so that the changes are applied after the table is loaded. `$(document).ready()` did not work with it. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: Modified to accommodate restated requirement in comment below.)

To strip "everything up to and including the '-'" from the text of first column table cells while leaving the rest untouched:

```js
// strip "everything up to and including the '-'"
// from table cell contents
function stripPrefix(tblCell) {
 // only evaluate first td in tr
  if (tblCell.previousElementSibling) {
    return;
  }
  const tNode = tblCell.firstChild;
  // ignore if table cell is empty
  if (!tNode) {
    return;
  }
  const chars = tNode.nodeValue.split('');
  const iFirstDash = chars.indexOf('-');
  if (iFirstDash === -1) { return; }
  tNode.nodeValue = chars.slice(iFirstDash+1).join('');
}

function stripAllPrefixes() {
  const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (const td of tds) {
    stripPrefix(td);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<h4>Strip "everything up to and including the '-'" from Table Cells</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A,B,C,D: 1 - Auswahl Wunschkarte : <b>Wähle eine Option</b></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B,C,D,E: 20 - A different leader : <b>should also be stripped</b></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oops no dash here <b>Just checking</b></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button onclick="stripAllPrefixes();">Strip All</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I cannot pass values through the function. If you see the demo page, you will have an idea. Can the given jQuery code be modified?

Comment: I think you still didn't understand the question. If you check the regex in the jQuery code it strips everything up to and including the `-`. I am not supplying anything like "A,B,C,D". It is just a reference, it can be anything. Care to read it again? :)

Comment: I missed the part where the requirement was stated  to strip "everything up to and including the –". I will update the code to accommodate this new requirement.

Comment: Thanks Terry, it worked. I appreciate that you used vanilla JS for this answer. For some reason the `TagName` did not work and the `ClassName` worked for me. I also had to include `window.onload = function()` replacing the button code.

Answer (score 1):

It does not effect the `b` tag, your code is working, you just need to use the right method and do the replacement to the HTML code and not the text nodes:

```
jQuery(".nbd-field-header label, .nbo-summary-table .ng-binding").html(function(i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,"");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the window.load(). Is there a better handler? So that I do not see the text change during the page load.

Comment: But now the b tag now gives out an output "Wahle eine option" on every single td. How did this code manipulate it?

Comment: Also using that code will also affect the other elements in the same row. So that is why I had to use `:first-child`.

Comment: This is just an example to where the issue is really is, you can still change the selector. For window.load, I think your elements are inserted later in the DOM and not during load time.